# How do I report the results of likelihood ratio test from glmmADMB?

Tags: glmm, likelihood-ratio, reporting

I want to test if an interaction is significant. My data are strongly overdispersed and contain repeated measures so I have a negative binomial GLMM model in `glmmADMB`.

I can compare the model containing the interaction term with a simpler additive model like this:

```
model1 <- glmmadmb(latfly ~ Playback*UR, 
               random= ~1|Location,
               data=first, family="nbinom2", link = "log")

model2 <- glmmadmb(latfly ~ Playback+UR, 
                   random= ~1|Location,
                   data=first, family="nbinom2", link = "log")

anova(model1, model2)
```

This produces the output:

```
Model 1: latfly ~ Playback + UR
Model 2: latfly ~ Playback * UR
  NoPar  LogLik Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
1     6 -617.62                       
2     8 -613.88  2     7.48  0.02375 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So, this shows a significant effect, but what do I report from this table? Normally when I run a likelihood ratio test I report the chi-squared value, but here I have deviance instead. Is this the same thing? Do I report the deviance value?